# Standard solution for displaying messages either on shell or with window managers gui

Tags: shell, kde, window-manager, gui

Is there a standard solution to display messages from within bash scripts eiter on the commandline if the shell is a login shell or in a new window in the present window manager's GUI? Specifically I am running kde which has the tool `kdialog` to display messages. However I would prefer a solution which is independent of KDE but uses KDE style if it is running. Also it should allow to ask for user input etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the commandline the standard solution is [`dialog (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dialog&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) which allows you to create interactive ncurses based dialogs, i.e:
[image: dialog selection dialog]

I think there is no definitive answer for an graphical interface from shell scripts but I consider [`zenity (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=zenity&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) as the de-facto tool for GUI interactions from the shell. As it is GTK based I am not a 100% sure about KDE themeing but it is possible as far as i know to use the KDE theme in GTK.